# Fetch internal tags in the xml using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

when I execute the below stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    
   
   
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="manu" select="node()|@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$manu"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting the below output:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<A1>
<B1>
<FILES>
<StudentData>
<Student>0001</Student>
<Student>0002</Student>
</StudentData>
</FILES>
</B1>
</A1>
```

Now I want to select only the StudentData:-

Expected Output:-

```
<StudentData>
<Student>0001</Student>
<Student>0002</Student>
</StudentData>
```

How to match this in XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

There a lots of ways. i.e. you could match on root and then just do a copy of the element using the xpath to that element like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="A1/B1/FILES/StudentData"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using an identity template? As far as I understand your problem, the simple solution is this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   
    <xsl:template match="StudentData" >
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to filter the empty lines out of your output, add a template matching the text nodes for that purpose:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   
    <xsl:template match="StudentData" >
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
      <!-- this tricky template prevents empty white lines in output -->
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```